# Android studio different screen sizes pixels

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-drawable

I made a little game for my android phone (1440x2960) and I used pixels to draw (without any layout):

```
canvas.drawBitmap(image, x, y, null);
```

The code is working fine with 1440x1960 screens but didn't pay attention to the different screen sizes (at 720p you can't see even half of the game). How can I solve this problem nicely? I know, that I can make different sizes for the image, but the real problem are the x and y coordinates. I thought about that maybe I can get the actual pixels of the screen, make a ratio, and multiply the coordinates with it, but it's harder than it looks (needs many changes) and should be a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

To get a phone's resolution, use

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
```

This object will contain the data you need to adjust the images accordingly, when used with the functions in [this documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics)

Also, have a look at converting dp to pixels and vice versa for appropriate scaling when referencing sizes in Java and XML simultaneously.